# Switching between Fragments and ListFragments causing errors

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-fragments

Im having issues populating a listview using fragments, I have a fragment class called **PagesFragment** that extends Fragment.. I also have a MainActivity that switches between my Fragments using a Menu.

I believe I need to extend ListFragment in order to populate my listview in my Fragment **'PagesFragment'** , however when I change all my classes to extend ListFragment, and change my cases to ListFragement in my MainActivity, I get an error when I try to run my code:

**Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'**

**Note:** Even after changing my id attributes to the correct values I still get the error.

## Code for Switching Fragments - using a SideMenu

```
 /**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    ListFragment listfragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        listfragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        listfragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        listfragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        listfragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        listfragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        listfragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } 



  else if (listfragment != null) {
        // do stuff if its a listfragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, listfragment)
            .commit();


 // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

## Code for Fragment - Can't populate ListView

```
public class PagesFragment extends ListFragment
{
// Counter for checking if Parsed Values are empty - To tell user event    has not started
int counter;

int ButtonCounter = 0;
private String gamename;
private String gamedate;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ProgressDialog pDialog2;
private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private ListView list1;
//Main variables 
private static String pt;
private static String pd;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inboxList;
// products JSONArray
JSONArray inbox = null;
JSONArray tour = null;
// Inbox JSON url
private static final String INBOX_URL = "http://www…";
// ALL JSON node namesapi_key=tD3djFMGmyWmDUdcgmBVFCd3
private static final String TAG_MESSAGES = "p";
private static final String TAG_ID = "p";
private static final String TAG_FROM = "g";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "t";
private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "r";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "s";
private static final String TAG_TOUR = "t";
private static final String TAG_TOURDATE = "d";



public PagesFragment(){}



   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.women_list, container, false);
     list1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
      new LoadInbox().execute();
      return rootView;
}




@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     // Hashmap for 
     inboxList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all INBOX messages by making HTTP Request
     * */


     Log.d("ITS RUNNING!", "Log Message");

    new LoadInbox().execute();

}

 private void populateList() 
 {
 }

     class LoadInbox extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () 
        {


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * getting Inbox JSON
         * */

}



    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
    {

         Log.d("Comments", "DoInBackground");
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(INBOX_URL, "GET",
                params);               

    try {
         Log.d("Comments", "Try Try Try Try");
            inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);

            inbox.toString();            
            // looping through All messages
            for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) 
            {
                  JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    //Get TOURNAMENT NAME
                    pgatour = c.getString(TAG_TOUR);
                    //Get TOURNAMENT DATE
                   tourdate = c.getString(TAG_TOURDATE);
                   //Get GOLFER NAME
                   String from = c.getString(TAG_FROM);

                    if(from != null && !from.isEmpty()) 
                    { 


                    }

                  //check if blank
                   else
                   { 

                      from = "--";        
                      counter++;
                   }      
                 //GET THUR   
                  String mailer = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

                  if(mailer != null && !mailer.isEmpty()) 
                  { 

                  }
                  else{ mailer = "--";}                         
                  ///GET ROUND 

                String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);

                if(subject != null && !subject.isEmpty()) 
                 { 

                 }

                else{ subject = "--";}

                 ///GET SCORE

                String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                 if(date != null && !date.isEmpty()) 
                   { 


                   }

                  else
                  { subject = "--";

                  }

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_FROM, from);
                map.put(TAG_EMAIL, mailer);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                inboxList.add(map);
            }

        } 

        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        if( pgatour != null)
         {
         }
         else
         {

         }

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run() 
             {  

         //This is for displaying the TOUR NAME & Data above button
         textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        textView.setText("  "+ pt + " - " + pd);

                            /**
                             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                             * */

         Log.d("Comments", "pt" +pd );



                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                   getActivity(), inboxList,
                                    R.layout.women_list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_FROM,TAG_DATE,TAG_EMAIL,TAG_SUBJECT},
                                    new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.date,R.id.mail,R.id.roundscore });
                            // updating listview
                     list1.setAdapter(adapter);
             }
    });



    //class end
    }

  }
```

## Layout CODE XML - Women_list.XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="POS"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
       />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="G"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="S"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
         />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="T"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="R"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textSize="11dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>


  <ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#E5E4E2"
    android:divider="#736F6E"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0"
         android:textSize="12dp"
         android:textColor="#90d2c6"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Refresh Scores"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:textSize="11dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
      />

  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

## MainActivity XML Layout:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />


<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

## Error Message: #

09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): Process:       info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 3814
09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): java.lang.RuntimeException:      Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a      ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
     09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
     09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
     09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):    at andr oid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
     09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
     09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):    at and  roid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1243)
     09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5969)
     09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
     09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):    ... 10 more

Comment: Update: Still not working - 3 days now stuck on this error

Comment: Update: Thanks Shadow Droid for the great answers, however non of the solutions work.

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation ofandroid:id="@id/android:list"
ListFragment [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html). Small section of it.

> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view.
>   However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by
>   returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView(LayoutInflater,
>   ViewGroup, Bundle). To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a
>   ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in
>   code)

**SOLUTION 1**
So if you are changing your fragment to ListFragment then make sure the id of your listView in the layout file must also change and it should be as follow

```
<ListView
 android:id="@id/android:list"
>
```

and inside onCreate it should be.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.women_list, container, false);
list1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

and then set the adapter
**OR**
**Solution 2**
inside onCreateView you do not need to find the view and directly set the adapter using following code in the onStart or onResume.

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**OR**
**Solution 3**
Inside onViewCreated or later callback method you use getListView as below
and then set the adapter...note-this if used in onCreateView; it would throw you exception

```
ListView list1  = getListView()
```

> But make sure you are not using same layout file elsewhere other then
>   ListFragment and ListActivity, bcoz if you do so you will get error.

**UPDATE BASED ON DISCUSSION AND TRIAL** 
Thank you for the simple layout R.layout.Women_list. I created a sample project using it with one main **Activity(which extended AppCompatActivity) and one Fragment(which extended ListFragment)** within activity. And did again a successful test of the above mentioned solution.
Now coming to your problem.

1. You might have multiple layouts in your application which might contain many listviews...so it not neccessary that all the listview should have id as **@id/android:list** *only those listview must have that id whose layout are either used in Fragment which extends ListFragment or Activiy which extends ListActivity* Also refer previous note.
2. I do not know why you are keeping the id of list view as android:list in the MainActivity layout is it really needed?
3. Please once again check all the fragments and activity along with layout used in application.It might have happen you did change the id of listview in one folder and left other so you need to change in every one of your res/layout/ and res/layout-.../ directories for that R.layout.Women_list

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Shadow, i've added all of your suggestions just trying to understand how I can customize the fragment layout. It's pretty confusing

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.women_list, container, false);
      list1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
       new LoadInbox().execute();
          return rootView;
    }

Comment: if possible can you add the R.layout.women_list to the question...And above solution is working or not?

Comment: Thanks I added the R.layout.women_list XML and Main Activity XML, also I updated my code with what i currently have. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Perhaps the issue is because i'm extending FragmentActivity in my main Activity.

1. Only two listviews are used in my code, @id/android:list  is used only in PagesFragment xml, and the other is in the MainActivity (android:id="@+id/list")

2. I changed mDrawerList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list); 

3. I've checked all layout folders

Comment: I believe your solutions only work if  my mainActivity extends ListActivity, however my code extends FragmentActivity

Comment: If you clearly see I have mentioned my mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity and not ListActivity....but my Fragment extends ListFragment so it works properly....Also please refer point 1 again I have use keyword OR...so in your program only PagesFragment should extends ListFragment that is enough...Also initially can you just comment the new LoadInbox().execute(); inside onCreateView and other section of code including asynctask and just check whether you able to access listView or not.