# How to create Custom Listview Layout for class that extends FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listview

I'm currently 4 days stuck on this issue, it's related to an issue with the use ListView for Fragments.

## ERROR

Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 3814 09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' 09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314) 09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 09-21 17:18:34.873: E/AndroidRuntime(3814):

## Code Structure

**PagesFragment** that extends ListFragment

It's XML has:

```
 ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

**MainActivity** that extends FragmentActivity

It's XML has

```
 ListView android:id="@+id/list"
```

**Background information:**

ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle). To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

## What I've tired

1. Changed XML Listview to @android:id/list
2. Created a custom fragment layout in Fragment
3. Checked all XML layout id's and tired a variety of id's

**I believe the above solutions only work if my main activity extends ListActivity, and not FragmentActivity .**

Comment: Can you share the code for `MainActivity`?

Comment: Hi hoomi, you can view the code here from a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697511/switching-between-fragments-and-listfragments-causing-errors/32698238?noredirect=1#comment53245200_32698238   Thanks a million for the help

Comment: Can I ask why does it need to be `ListFragment` not a normal Fragment with custom layout?

Comment: In my PagesFragment class I'm populating a listview with a ListAdapter, and I use setListAdapter. Im using a ListFragment for that.

Comment: Yeah but you can do the same with normal fragment. You can use any id for your listview. For setting adapter you can use `ListView.setAdapter()`

Comment: yes really. It is much easier

Comment: See I first thought that would, my listview was not getting populated,  im calling   new LoadInbox().execute(); in my  onCreateView(). But it's not working, I assumed i needed to extend ListFragment for it to work

Comment: Hi Hoomi, i got my JSON working, however i can't seem to update my  listview, everywhere online tells me I need to use a ListFragment to do it

Comment: They are lying. And you need to share your own code not some similar question code. Code is never the same... If it was just use their answer. right?